# String problems after NSUTF8StringEncoding

Tags: xcode, json

I try to download a JSON string from a server, which doesn't look the way it should.
sorry for that formatting, first time using stackoverflow..

As you can see in the comparison from the received string and the var_dump from php,
the key's from `arr[LISTING][<this ones>]` are removed.. and so my further JSON decoding does treat the entry from `arr[LISTING][<this one>]` as one value, instead of another array sub-dimension

Any ideas?

What I tried:

```
NSData *serverRes = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *serverRes_str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:serverRes encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",serverRes_str);
```

what this looks like:

```
{"STATUS":{"RESULT":"OK","CODE":205,"INFO":"GET_PROJECTS","AUTHENTICATED":1,"USERID":1,"ACCESS":1000,"SYSTEM_NAME":"Testdatei","SSL":false,"IDENTIFIER":""},"CONTENT":{"GET_PROJECTS":{"COUNT":7,"LISTING":[{"ID":"1","NAME":"Devel","CREATION_DATE":"1357116685","CREATED_BY":"admin","TYPE":"PROJECT","PUBLIC":false,"PRIVAT":false,"ACCESS":3,"THUMBNAIL":""},{"ID":"30","NAME":"p5","CREATION_DATE":"1365866791","CREATED_BY":"admin","TYPE":"PROJECT","PUBLIC":false,"PRIVAT":false,"ACCESS":3,"THUMBNAIL":""},{"ID":"29","NAME":"p4","CREATION_DATE":"1365866785","CREATED_BY":"admin","TYPE":"PROJECT","PUBLIC":false,"PRIVAT":false,"ACCESS":3,"THUMBNAIL":""},{"ID":"28","NAME":"p3","CREATION_DATE":"1365866780","CREATED_BY":"admin","TYPE":"PROJECT","PUBLIC":false,"PRIVAT":false,"ACCESS":3,"THUMBNAIL":""},{"ID":"27","NAME":"p2","CREATION_DATE":"1365866773","CREATED_BY":"admin","TYPE":"PROJECT","PUBLIC":false,"PRIVAT":false,"ACCESS":3,"THUMBNAIL":""},{"ID":"26","NAME":"p1","CREATION_DATE":"1365866767","CREATED_BY":"admin","TYPE":"PROJECT","PUBLIC":false,"PRIVAT":false,"ACCESS":3,"THUMBNAIL":""},{"ID":"4","NAME":"Testimmortals","CREATION_DATE":"1362388820","CREATED_BY":"admin","TYPE":"PROJECT","PUBLIC":false,"PRIVAT":false,"ACCESS":3,"THUMBNAIL":""}]}}}
```

what it should look like:

```
array(2) {
  ["COUNT"]=>
  int(7)
  ["LISTING"]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    array(9) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["NAME"]=>
      string(5) "Devel"
      ["CREATION_DATE"]=>
      string(10) "1357116685"
      ["CREATED_BY"]=>
      string(5) "admin"
      ["TYPE"]=>
      string(7) "PROJECT"
      ["PUBLIC"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["PRIVAT"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["ACCESS"]=>
      int(3)
      ["THUMBNAIL"]=>
      string(92) ""
    }
    [1]=>
    array(9) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(2) "30"
      ["NAME"]=>
      string(2) "p5"
      ["CREATION_DATE"]=>
      string(10) "1365866791"
      ["CREATED_BY"]=>
      string(5) "admin"
      ["TYPE"]=>
      string(7) "PROJECT"
      ["PUBLIC"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["PRIVAT"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["ACCESS"]=>
      int(3)
      ["THUMBNAIL"]=>
      string(93) ""
    }
    [2]=>
    array(9) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(2) "29"
      ["NAME"]=>
      string(2) "p4"
      ["CREATION_DATE"]=>
      string(10) "1365866785"
      ["CREATED_BY"]=>
      string(5) "admin"
      ["TYPE"]=>
      string(7) "PROJECT"
      ["PUBLIC"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["PRIVAT"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["ACCESS"]=>
      int(3)
      ["THUMBNAIL"]=>
      string(93) ""
    }
    [3]=>
    array(9) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(2) "28"
      ["NAME"]=>
      string(2) "p3"
      ["CREATION_DATE"]=>
      string(10) "1365866780"
      ["CREATED_BY"]=>
      string(5) "admin"
      ["TYPE"]=>
      string(7) "PROJECT"
      ["PUBLIC"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["PRIVAT"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["ACCESS"]=>
      int(3)
      ["THUMBNAIL"]=>
      string(93) ""
    }
    [4]=>
    array(9) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(2) "27"
      ["NAME"]=>
      string(2) "p2"
      ["CREATION_DATE"]=>
      string(10) "1365866773"
      ["CREATED_BY"]=>
      string(5) "admin"
      ["TYPE"]=>
      string(7) "PROJECT"
      ["PUBLIC"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["PRIVAT"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["ACCESS"]=>
      int(3)
      ["THUMBNAIL"]=>
      string(93) ""
    }
    [5]=>
    array(9) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(2) "26"
      ["NAME"]=>
      string(2) "p1"
      ["CREATION_DATE"]=>
      string(10) "1365866767"
      ["CREATED_BY"]=>
      string(5) "admin"
      ["TYPE"]=>
      string(7) "PROJECT"
      ["PUBLIC"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["PRIVAT"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["ACCESS"]=>
      int(3)
      ["THUMBNAIL"]=>
      string(93) ""
    }
    [6]=>
    array(9) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["NAME"]=>
      string(13) "Testimmortals"
      ["CREATION_DATE"]=>
      string(10) "1362388820"
      ["CREATED_BY"]=>
      string(5) "admin"
      ["TYPE"]=>
      string(7) "PROJECT"
      ["PUBLIC"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["PRIVAT"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["ACCESS"]=>
      int(3)
      ["THUMBNAIL"]=>
      string(92) ""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the JSON library that comes for iOS ?
It has a really handy method like this :

```
NSArray *responseValues = [responseString JSONValue];
```

or

```
NSDictionary *responseValues = [responseString JSONValue];
```

- You can get it as array or dictionary whatever, because `JSONValue` method returns an `id`, so you can adapt to whatever you're receiving.

You can find the library here:
https://github.com/stig/json-framework

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, since the string is already wrong, it's not the fault of the json decoding.. i think it's even the api.. let me dig in to this..

Comment: OK, looks like i fixed it -> json_encode($array,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) missed that force..

Comment: so the problem was from your php file ?